# How to update extracted value of JSON object from one http request, and re-use it in another http request in JMeter

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter

I am working one JMeter task. In that task, I need to extract JSON from the http request, and update some element for all child element within that JSON object, and re-use that updated JSON in another HTTP request.

1. inside the JSON there is an array which has minimum 500 Onjects;
2. I only need to update the two elements of each object, and use it in the next request

what I am thinking is to use JavaScript, and from what I have searched so far, I should be able to use JSR223 Sampler to run my JavaScript,

and I also already have the code tested that it works.

my dilemma is that the value I am using to update the value inside the objects were not defined within this code block, those two values are extracted using another regular expression method within JMeter.

there are at least two Regular Expression Extractor; one extracts the array of objects from JSON response,

another one extracts two values from another response.

now I am trying to use them together in another sampler to conform a new array of objects and use in the next request.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Using data from "another" regular expression extractor shouldn't be a problem as long as it's executed before you're building the JSON Payload.

The extracted values will remain in the [thread local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) until:

- the thread (virtual user) is terminated
- the values are updated (i.e. Regular Expression Extractor is executed in another iteration)
- the values are removed (if they're big enough and you don't need them anymore it makes sense to delete the variables)

The only thing I would suggest is reconsidering using JavaScript which is some form of a performante anti-pattern (especially when it comes to 500+ objects). [The recommended scripting language in JMeter is Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)